# Windows 8 - LAN connection doesn't startup on reboot

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, network-adapter

I don't know what's gone wrong, but of late whenever I reboot my Win 8 Pro x64 box, the ethernet connection doesn't turn on by itself. I have to go into network settings and manually disable/re-enable it.
Should I check for any disabled services?
I rarely reboot my box, only when an update requires it(I use suspend instead of shutdown), so it usually goes upto 3 weeks or more before rebooting.

It's a built in controller on my Intel motherboard - 82579V, drivers are up to date, etc etc.

Comment: You should add more detail about your computer. Which network controller is it? Check for driver updates, try to uninstall and reinstall the device. With my network adapter I experienced similar problems which I fixed by disabling the Wake-on-LAN, magic packet and similar feature in the Advanced Tab of the device properties.